# trying to understand this proof of sylows theorem that say the number of p-sylow subgroups is 1+kp

Tags: group-theory, proof-explanation, sylow-theory

I'm Very confused as to what my lecturer means in the final few lines of a proof of one of sylows theorems means. The theorem in question is the one that says the number of sylow P-subgroups is 1+kp.

Here's the part of the proof I'm confused about :

Let S be the set of all subsets of order $p^\alpha$ let $A\in S$ and let G act on it by right multiplication

.

.

.

It follows then that the number of P-sylow subgroups is the number of orbits of S of size m . let $n_p$ be the number of p sylow subgroups then

$$
\begin{aligned}
&\ |S|=\sum_{\text{orbits of size m}}|O|+\sum_{\text{orbits size >m}}|O|\\
\Rightarrow &\ |S|=n_pm+mpr\\ \Rightarrow &\ \binom{mp^\alpha}{p^\alpha}/m=n_p+pr \\ \Rightarrow &\ \binom{mp^\alpha}{p^\alpha}/m\equiv n_p\pmod p
\end{aligned}$$

But we know that the cyclic group of order $mp^{\alpha}$ has exactly one subgroup of order $p^{\alpha}$ Thus  $ \binom{mp^\alpha}{p^\alpha}/m\equiv1\pmod p$ and so $n_p\equiv1\pmod p$

I understodd the rest of the proof just fine , but this has really stumped me. for starters I'm not familiar with the notation he seems to be using to describe the size of S( the brackets term). secondly I don't understand how he made the jump $\binom{mp^\alpha}{p^\alpha}/m\equiv1\pmod p$ and so $n_p\equiv1\pmod p$

Could anyone plese help me to understand this ?

Note: the dots represent part of the proof I left out if needs be I can add it for context but I thought it seemed superfluous given that this little part is the source of all my confusion.

Comment: Not sure I can help (yet), but I'm curious how $m$ is defined.

Comment: When you say "bracket term" do you mean $\binom{mp^a}{p^s}$? That's a binomial coefficient.

Comment: @ChrisCuster No doubt the order of $G$ is $mp^a$ where $p\nmid m$.

Comment: Yeah.  I figured something like that.   I'm still a little stuck on the first part. @LordSharktheUnknown

Comment: The quotient equals $n_p$ modulo $p$ for *every* group of order $mn_p$ (as only its order was used in the proof until here) independent of its structure, so you can calculate the value by looking at any specific group of this order.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown so he just means there that there is $mn_p+mpr$ ways of choosing $p^{\alpha}$ objects from $mp^{\alpha}$ things ?

Comment: @ChrisCuster lord sharak is correct in how he defined m but I there anything else you would like me to clarify about the question ?

Comment: I don't understand why we are allowed to consider the cyclic group  of order $mp^{\alpha}$, or how this gives us ${mp^{\alpha}\choose p^{\alpha}}/m\cong1\pmod p$.

Comment: @ChrisCuster every group of prime order is cylic, but I don't know why we can deduce that ${\mp^{\alpha}\choose p^{\alpha}}/m\cong1\pmod p $ either

Comment: $mp^{\alpha}$ isn't prime;  but I see @j.p. addressed my first question.

Comment: @ChrisCuster oh damn you're right I'd been thinking of it wrong. I don't really understand j.p's answer could you explain it to me ?

Comment: The point seems to be that any group can be used, since nothing but the order was used to get there.  Clearly $n_p=1$ for the cyclic group.   Maybe this clears it up.